# What is the maximum volume of $N$-D slice of an $M$-D hypercube?

Tags: geometry, volume, cross-sections

Consider a unit hypercube of M dimensions. We wish to make a cut of dimension N through it. What is the largest N-D size (length, area, volume, ...) we can achieve, $S(M, N)$, and what cut gives it?

Examples:

- $S(M=2, N=1) = \sqrt2$

  - Linear cut through a square
  - Largest slice is the diagonal
  - Length $\sqrt{1^2 + 1^2}$
- $S(M=3, N=1) = \sqrt3$

  - Linear cut through a cube
  - Largest slice is the space diagonal
  - Length $\sqrt{1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2}$
- $S(M=3, N=2) = \sqrt 2$

  - Planar cut through a cube
  - Largest slice is the plane through the diagonal
    [image]
  - Area $\sqrt 2 \cdot 1$

Bits of this function are easy to generalize:
$$
S(M, N) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
   \sqrt M & : N = 1\\
   ? & : 1 < N < M\\
   1 & : N = M\\
   0 & : N > M\\
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

Can we generalize for $N = 2, 3, ...$?

Comment: I believe the second example should be $S(M = 1, N = 1)$.

Comment: @Travis: We were both wrong. Fixed

Comment: I guess $\sqrt{M-N+1}$.

Comment: @Eric Oops, I mistyped (too); of course, I meant $M = 3$...

Comment: @kennytm: That's definitely a lower bound, but I'm not sure it's optimal.

Comment: Is it possible to pull a $\sqrt 2 \times \sqrt 3 $ rectangle out of a 5-cube?

Comment: Yes, with edge vectors $\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1&1&1 \end{bmatrix}$. Sorry @kennytm, counterexample of area $\sqrt 6 \neq \sqrt{5 - 2 + 1}$

Answer (score 2):

$S(M,M-1)=\sqrt{2}$ for all $M\ge1$; this is [a theorem of Keith Ball from 1986](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2046239?seq=1).

$S(4,2)$ is the smallest term not specified by this result; it is at least $2$, by taking the plane $x_1=x_2, x_3=x_4$, which forms a $\sqrt{2}\times\sqrt{2}$ square. I suspect this is optimal, but I don't see an easy way to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to put into words, without proof, the idea that has been floating around here.
Let $M=aN+b$.
Split the $M$ dimensions into $b$ groups of $a+1$ and $N-b$ groups of $a$.
Take the diagonal in each group, of length $\sqrt a$ or $\sqrt{a+1}$.
The product of all these diagonals is
$$\sqrt{a^{N-b}(a+1)^b}$$

Comment: Is it true that, when $N-1$ dimensions are fixed and the $N$th changes linearly, the second derivative of the volume is positive?  Then the maximum happens when a vertex's coordinate hits 0 or 1.  Then repeat until all vertices' coordinates are 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

As a lower bound $S(M, N) \ge \sqrt{M - N + 1}$

where the slice is a $\underbrace{1 \times 1 \times \cdots}_{N-1} \times \sqrt{M - N + 1}$ cuboid

---

Choose the first $N-1$ axes of the hypercube to lie in the slice-space. (Possibly non-optimal)

A $M - N + 1$ subspace remains, from which we want to find the longest 1-area.

This is $S(M - N + 1, 1) = \sqrt{M - N + 1}$.