# Maximum volume of a slice of cuboid.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, puzzle, computational-geometry

Similar to this question:
[What is the maximum volume of $N$-D slice of an $M$-D hypercube?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259085/what-is-the-maximum-volume-of-n-d-slice-of-an-m-d-hypercube)

Suppose we have a 3D cuboid with sides of length $a, b, c$. What is the maximum area of a slice of this cuboid?

My first guess would be that assuming $a$ is the largest, then the maximum area is $a*\sqrt{b^2 + c^2}$, but I'm not sure this is true.

Comment: You could show that modifying gradually the slice rotation reduces the area.